# Programming receive tone on Kenwood V71A

Tags: kenwood, radio-programming, tone-squelch, kenwood-tm-v71a

Is it possible to program a receive tone on a Kenwood TM-V71A, and if so, how is it done?

I initially thought I had my answer when I came across [Kenwood TH-D72A: what's the difference between Tone and CTCSS?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/14829/kenwood-th-d72a-whats-the-difference-between-tone-and-ctcss) . It appeared that I just needed to use the `CTCSS` option instead of the `Tone` option.

Regarding CTCSS, the manual says:

> You may sometimes want to hear calls only from specific persons. The
> Continuous Tone Coded Squelch System (CTCSS) allows you to ignore (not
> hear) unwanted calls from other persons who are using the same
> frequency. To do so, select the same CTCSS tone as selected by the
> other persons in your group. A CTCSS tone is subaudible and is
> selectable from among 42 tone frequencies.

and later:

> When you are called: The transceiver squelch opens only when the
> selected CTCSS tone is received.

However, after additional testing, selecting `CTCSS` doesn't seem to be working as described. I'm trying this on our club repeater, and using a receive tone was specifically recommended to me by the person who runs it, who indicated that it uses the same tone in both directions. Using the radio's tone scan function seems to confirm that the repeater is transmitting the expected tone. But when listening to a conversation on the repeater, and cycling through the tone options, the squelch doesn't open when using `CTCSS`--only when using the basic `Tone` option.

What else could I be missing here?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the tone value and CTCSS value are stored separately in the 71A - you may have set the tone value to 100, but then when you go into CTCSS it will use the default 88.5 until you set it for CTCSS mode.

Comment: @user3486184 Ugh, that's what it was. Another faulty assumption on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tone values for Tone mode and CTCSS mode are stored separately in the TM-V71A. If you set the value when you set up for tone and then change into CTCSS mode, you'll be back at the default 88.5.

Make sure to set the tone value to your desired tone after entering CTCSS mode.